# I'm trying to click on a elemnet after inputing data in this field:

Tags: vba

I'm trying to click on a elemnet after inputing data in this field:

```
<form action="/bg/Proverka-na-smetka-za-elektroenergiya" method="post" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
<input type="Text" name="kin" value="1100328558" style="color: #8D8D8D; width: 124px; height: 22px; border: 1px solid #ADADAD; font-size: 12px; padding: 0 0 0 8px; float: left; margin: 5px 6px 0px 0; " onclick="javascript:if(this.value=='Клиентски номер')this.value='';">
<input type="Image" src="img/search_bg.jpg" style="margin: 6px 0 8px 0; float: left; "><br>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

How I can use IE.Document.getElementBy by VBA?

This is the code I'm using:

```
Sub energo()
    Dim ieEnergo As Object
    Dim docEnergo As HTMLDocument

    Set ieEnergo = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieEnergo.Visible = True

    ieEnergo.navigate "https://www.energo-pro.bg/bg/Proverka-na-smetka-za-elektroenergiya"

    Do While ieEnergo.Busy Or ieEnergo.readyState  4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set docEnergo = ieEnergo.document

    For rowNoEnergo = 2 To 2
        docEnergo.getElementById("kin").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

    Next
```

Comment: I've added the code you posted as an answer into your question.  The `edit` button to update your questions is just below the `vba` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "Mention URL here.."
'Code to update value in input
IE.Document.getElementByName("kin")(0).Value = "Put Value Here"
'Then submit
IE.Document.getElementById("submit").Click
```

Comment: please update your question and add VBA code you are executing..

Comment: @ИвайлоИлиев replace this `docEnergo.getElementById("kin").Value` with `docEnergo.getElementByName("kin").Value` as you are not using `Id` attribute in html. Or you can add `id` attribute in html

Comment: now make Run-time error 438 can you see this web https://www.energo-pro.bg/bg/Proverka-na-smetka-za-elektroenergiya I try autoFill and auto submit

Comment: Sorry...i got it. Because `getElementByName` returns a `collection` so you will have to use `docEnergo.getElementByName("kin")(0).value="test"`

Comment: now RunTime 91 in debug here "docEnergo.getElementById("submit").Click" Please help me I really need to make it to work.

Comment: submit button is not there in your html code. i have put that in my answer just to give you an idea that how it works. You will have to update it for an image that is there in your html code.

Comment: I cant update because web is on another person, I need to get data when I put value.